# Polygon shapefile with null values?

Tags: shapefile

Does anyone know where I can find a sample shapefile that has null entries in it (preferably a polygon shapefile)?

I'm not sure how to create one with null entries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be warned that a lot of software reading SHP files do not support null-values for the geometry. Even older versions of ArcView had problems.

I have created a sample here:
http://www.routeware.dk/temp/shp_null_sample.zip
It has 3 records, the 2nd has no geometry.

Comment: Which versions of ArcView?  I recall that AV 2.x and 3.x would create null geometries whenever they created a new shapefile ('FTab' object in Avenue), so null geometries were common and completely supported.

Comment: null geoms are supported, they're a valid value (unknown) for a geometry.  Trouble is lots of software use the geometry without first checking if it's null, then bad things happen such as crashes .  That's why there is a gp tool Data Management\CheckGeometry, if the software has trouble with a fc, this is typically the first thing to check.

Comment: I don't quite remember. AV3 or AV8 perhaps? A new SHP file has no records at all, that isn't the same as a null geometry.

Comment: It's a simple matter to add new records to a new shapefile (ctrl-A in the View GUI of AV 3.x will do it).  They automatically have null shapes.  Null shapes were also produced as the result of invalid operations, such as hard-projecting shapes that are outside the domain of a projection.  AV 3.x generally had no problems with them.  I think problems may have arisen in AV 8 and later: in effect, ESRI's newer software did not conform to their own specs.

Comment: I don't need it but the link in this answer is broken.

Comment: @UffeKousgaard, I have applied a strikethrough to the portion of this post which pertained to a link which is now dead.  Can you please elaborate on this answer to prevent removal of the post, which may result in lost reputation.

Comment: The file is back.

Answer (score 10):

I assume you mean null for the geometry/shape column, because shapefiles don't support null for any field type except the geometry and (i hear) for date fields.

The code below creates 1 shapefile with 1 record/feature that has a null poly geometry.

```
  import arcpy
  import os
  outfc = r'c:\temp\outfc.shp'
  arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.dirname(outfc)
  arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(arcpy.env.workspace,os.path.basename(outfc), 'polygon')
  cur = arcpy.InsertCursor(outfc)
  row = cur.newRow()
  cur.insertRow(row)
  del(row)
  del(cur)
  r = arcpy.CheckGeometry_management(outfc,'in_memory\\outtable')
  print r.getMessages()
```

I run it and get this which is what i'd expect

**WARNING 000442: null geometry at 0 in c:\temp\outfc.shp**

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on ESRI software, at least I can speak for ArcGIS 9.3, then shapefiles do not support nulls.  I ran into this problem a few weeks ago and spent a day investigating.  I found this link particularly illuminating 
http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=125464.  It seems the only way to support nulls within ESRI shapefiles is to use geodatabases (then the shapefiles become featureclasses. I used file a geodatabase).  To support nulls, I ended up making a geodatabase and creating the featureclasses (otherwise known as shapefiles) inside the file geodatabase (this will support nulls) as opposed to creating a shapefile and then importing it into the geodatabase (this will not support nulls). If I remember correctly, you also have to explicitly state in the field properties that you want nulls to be supported. Here is the link that might help [How to create a feature class in a file geodatabase in ArcGIS 9.3 with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11974/how-to-create-a-feature-class-in-a-file-geodatabase-in-arcgis-9-3-with-python)