# Creating feature class in file geodatabase in ArcGIS Desktop with arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, feature-class

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.

What I am looking to do is create a file geodatabase and add a feature class directly into that file geodatabase, as opposed to creating a feature class outside the file geodatabase and then importing it into the file geodatabase.  The reason I need to be able to create the feature class directly in a file geodatabase is because I need to have attribute table columns that are nullable, whereas if I create a feature class outside the file geodatabase and then import it into the file geodatabase, nulls will not be allowed. Please correct me if I am wrong.  Currently, I am able to create the file geodatabase, but I can't add a feature class directly to the file geodatabase.
The code I currently have is:

```
 import os, arcgisscripting
 gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
 gp.Overwriteoutput = 1
 cwd = "C:\\Path\\To\\directory"
 gp.workspace = cwd
 gp.toolbox = "management"
 number = '1'
 fileGDB = "test_%s.gdb" % number
 shpFile = "file_%s.shp" % number
 gp.CreateFileGDB(cwd, fileGDB)
 gp.CreateFeatureclass(fileGDB, shpFile, "POINT", '#', '#', '#', '#')
 gp.addfield ( shpFile, fieldName, "FLOAT", "20","20", "#", "#", "NULLABLE", "#", "#")
 ...the rest of my code here
```

Comment: Why are you using a modulus when defining your file GDB and shpFile name?

Comment: @Nathanus: in this context `%` is a [string formatting operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), so the result is 'test_1.gdb'

Comment: @9monkeys: you have a subtle typo with `"C:\Path\\To\\directory"` .. make this either `"C:\\Path\\To\\directory"` or `r"C:\Path\To\directory"`

Comment: Are you trying to import a shapefile into the GDB? In that case you would use FeatureClassToFeatureClass. I think you do have some terminology confused.

Comment: @Mike Yes, thanks, that was a typo. I don't want to import a shapefile into the GDB because the shapefile needs to be able accomodate nulls, which shapefiles can't (see this very interesting post http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=125464) while GDBs can.  That being said, if I build the shapefile outside of the GDB then I won't be able to use nulls whereas if I build inside of a GDB then I can use nulls.

Comment: @Nathanus Yes, Mike is correct.  I am using this to reduce the number of places I would have to otherwise manually type the featureclass name and the GDB name.  Since, I ran my code over many times in trials and errors this made it a lot easier to keep up with my versions and reduce manual typing.

Comment: @9monkeys Ah, yes. I always forget about that use for it. I never got into the habit of string formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your first problem is that you're appending ".shp" to your output geodatabase featureclass. Remove this and your problem may be solved.

```
...     
....
shpFile = "file_%s" % number  #--removed ".shp"
...
...the rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the steps you are doing comprise of geoprocessing tools, you could just build it in ModelBuilder and export out the script to python.  I did this in 9.3.1, I'm not sure if the script is the same in 9.3, see code below.

```
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")


# Local variables...
test_gdb = "C:\\Temp\\test.gdb"
Temp = "C:\\Temp"
fclass = "C:\\Temp\\test.gdb\\fclass"
test_gdb__2_ = "C:\\Temp\\test.gdb"
fclass__2_ = "C:\\Temp\\test.gdb\\fclass"

# Process: Create File GDB...
gp.CreateFileGDB_management(Temp, "test")

# Process: Create Feature Class...
gp.CreateFeatureclass_management(test_gdb__2_, "fclass", "POLYGON", "", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", "", "", "0", "0", "0")

# Process: Add Field...
gp.AddField_management(fclass, "number", "LONG", "2", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

You may have to reference the toolboxes that you are using.