# PostGIS automatically creating geometries after importing using QGIS DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, geometry

I have a shapefile consisting of linestrings, in which some of the features have null geometry. Yet, after importing it to PostGIS, using QGIS' DB Manager, a geometry is created for those features (what it does is create a small segment on top of another existing linestring).

Has anyone ever seen this happen? This problem doesn't happen when I import the shapefile using OpenGeo's pgShapeLoader. Is it a bug of DB Manager, or am I not configuring it correctly for importing?

I'm using QGIS 2.2.0 for mac, and PostGIS 10.1.0

Comment: Sounds like null values in shapefiles [aren't well supported in general](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/polygon-shapefile-with-null-values).  Probably a bug.